# WSO2 APIM 4.2 Throttle Response Message

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I tried to user the throttling function on WSO2 APIM 4.2 and I found that the response message still using UTC as the time while I already set the country and timezone to gmt+7

it shows like this

Error: Too Many Requests

Response body
Download
{
"code": "900803",
"message": "Message throttled out",
"description": "You have exceeded your quota .You can access API after 2024-Jan-25 02:02:00+0000 UTC",
"nextAccessTime": "2024-Jan-25 02:02:00+0000 UTC"
}

[image]

is there any way for me to change it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no configuration to set this in the source code. It sets the UTC time zone there - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v9.28.222/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/throttling/ThrottleHandler.java#L1300

If you are using the open source version, you can try to patch.